# let a tableView inherit a custom scrollview delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

What I'd like to do is.

1. override scrollView's delegate method (eg, scrollViewDidEndDragging)
2. use it for my scrollView & tableView

What I have now is,

1. MyScrollView's delegate overrides scrollViewDidEndDragging
2. MySuperTableViewController(subclass of UITableView) overrides scrollViewDidEndDragging, and let MyChildTableViewController subclasses MySuperTableViewController

Apparently, the same scrollViewDidEndDragging code is duplicated over two places, how can I place the code in one place and share it?

Following is the code that I'd like to share for my scrollView and tableView

```
#import "OverlayTableViewController.h"


@interface OverlayTableViewController()
{
CADisplayLink *_displayLink;
}
@end

@implementation OverlayTableViewController

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    [self startDisplayLinkIfNeeded];
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView*)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if(!decelerate)
        [self stopDisplayLink];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self stopDisplayLink];
}


- (void)startDisplayLinkIfNeeded
{
    if(!_displayLink)
    {
        _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(display)];
        [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
    }
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [_displayLink invalidate];
    _displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)display
{
    //
}

@end
```

Comment: might be better off posting some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way put all the common delegate logic into something new, calling it something like CommonScrollViewDelegate.  It might need a property like displayLinkTarget and any other properties that are custom to the classes that use it.

Any of those classes can just set their scroll delegate to it like this:

```
CommonScrollViewDelegate *commonDelegate = [[CommonScrollViewDelegate alloc] init];

commonDelegate.displayLinkTarget = self; // or add this to the init method if you want
myScrollView.delegate = commonDelegate;
```

Then your code in the CommonScrollViewDelegate stay essentially the same, with minor tweaks like this:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) id displayLinkTarget;
// etc.
@synthesize displayLinkTarget = _displayLinkTarget;

- (void)startDisplayLinkIfNeeded
{
    if(!_displayLink)
    {
        _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self.displayLinkTarget
                                                   selector:@selector(display)];
        [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
    }
}
```